# Wordpress navbar and slider

Tags: html, css, wordpress, slider, navbar

I have this website here built in wordpress: [Cerabora](https://cerabora.ma).

In mobile view, if you try to slide from the left side of the home page first slider it will not work, but it works when try it from the opposite side.

I need a solution please respond.

I tried many solutions like changing the z-index of both the navbar and the slider but it did not work as supposed to.

Comment: Could you please provide screenshots or images showing the slider behavior on your WordPress website? This will help me better understand the issue and provide an accurate solution. Any additional details about your website's setup would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.